# Reliable, lightweight communication protocol for mobile

Tags: android, networking, sensors, mqtt

I am looking for a communication protocol to use in my mobile application. The first target is Android, but it would actually be very nice if it is supported in other platforms like iOS, OSX and Windows 8.
The main goals are:

**It has to be very energy efficient**, the messages we are sending are actually very small and there is no communication most of the time (it's for sensing, and updates are not very frequent)

**It should support intermittent connectivity and guarantee message delivery** It is important for the application not to miss updates

**Should be able to support encryption for some or all messages** Some of the sensor data contain privacy sensitive information

**Should not require a constant connection ** So that the application can be put to sleep when is not in use. Google Cloud Messaging works great when it comes to receiving messages from the server, but the problem is having something to send from the clients without requiring to keep a connection active.

The previous version was using XMPP and JSON messages, but I think that is a bad idea, since it requires a constant connection, and it is not meant to be energy efficient.

I want to use Protocol Buffers instead of JSON for a more compact representation and faster serialization, but I am undecided on the transport. MQTT came up when searching, and it may make sense, but its encryption support is not great, and it seems to require keeping a connection. I wonder if there are any other suitable candidates to consider. Any recommendations or thoughts?